# Threads behaving oddly

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading

The following .Net 5 multithreaded code which runs on Windows 10 should have computed the `_sum` non-deterministically, say 2,4 and 8. However, the `_sum` is always 10, i.e., the correct answer. It seems as if there were a lock already applied on `_sum`.

Could anyone shed some light on this problem?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace MtAdd
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int _sum = 0; //shared resource  
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var threads = new Thread[10];

            //Add 1 to _sum for ten times. 
            for (var i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
            {
                threads[i] = new Thread(AddOne);
                threads[i].Start();
            }

            foreach (var t in threads)
            {
                t.Join();
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] sum = {1}", 
                              Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, 
                              _sum);
        }

        private static void AddOne()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] AddOne called", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            _sum++; //critical section
        }
    }
}
```

```
[4] AddOne called
[5] AddOne called
[7] AddOne called
[6] AddOne called
[8] AddOne called
[9] AddOne called
[10] AddOne called
[11] AddOne called
[12] AddOne called
[13] AddOne called
[1] sum = 10
```

Comment: Protip: generally speaking you should **never** need to use `Thread` directly. If you think you need to use `Thread` then you probably don't.

Comment: Hint: add a `Thread.Sleep(100);` in `AddOne()`. I expect the scenario is this: the execution time of `AddOne` is less than the overhead of creating and starting a thread.

Comment: Your program is incorrect, plain and simple: C# and .NET does not guarantee cross-thread atomicity when mutating scalar value-types, even `int` and `bool` (and `volatile` does not do what you think it does either). Either use an explicit `lock` statement or use `Interlocked.Increment`.

Comment: @Llama That isn't going to fix the fundamental thread-safety correctness problems with the program.

Comment: @Dai You might want to re-read the question. OP is expecting this code **is not** thread-safe, and is wondering why they get 10 when updating the value from multiple threads would likely lead to a value <10.

Comment: @Dai Anyway, my guess is this: it's effectively running synchronously because `AddOne` execution time < thread startup execution time, which is why OP gets 10 and not some number <10 as they expect.

Comment: Threading race bugs depend on timing to do their evil deed.  In this case two threads must read the value of sum at the exact same time before incrementing it to demonstrate the race.  That can certainly happen, you however made it unlikely by using Console.WriteLine().  That takes an internal lock that ensures two thread cannot write to the console at the same time.  Thus ensuring these threads are unlikely to arrive at sum++ at the same time.  It now takes the machine getting busy, accidentally delaying a thread.  Remove Console.WriteLine(), sum to a million to increase the odds.

Comment: Additionally to @HansPassant comment also the things done within the thread are so tiny, that a thread could be finished before start returns, the next thread is created and also being started. Possibly use a semaphore within the thread to wait on and release it when all threads are up and running to increase possibility.

Comment: If you change the implementaiton of `AddOne()` to loop you'll see it going wrong: `for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) _sum++; `

Comment: @Llama Ah yes, sorry, it's 3:30am here... I should go

Comment: @Dai No worries :)

Comment: Thanks for your input! Indeed, a former C# MVP used the code in an online course about CLR Threading. I couldn't reproduce the indeterminstic behaviour of it even though I complied the code againt .Net Framework 2.0, or rewrote it with LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Three things to increase the probability get a "wrong" answer:

- get rid of `Console.WriteLine`: see @Hans explanation in comments
- increase the concurrency: ie if 10 is not enough, try 1_000_000 threads
- use `Task.Run(AddOne)`: it will run `AddOne` in the [thread pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool). It costs very little runtime to start a thread from here because the CLR keeps a pool of already-started threads. Whereas `new Thread(action).Start` can take around 100ms to actually create a new thread.

The code below prints 982266 rather than 1000000 on my computer. Try on yours and let us know:

```
    var tasks = new Task[1_000_000];

    for (var i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
        tasks[i] = Task.Run(AddOne);

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    Console.WriteLine(_sum);
```

Comment: *"try 1_000_000 threads"*, `var tasks = new Task[1_000_000];` <== tasks are not threads!

Comment: Indeed a Task is not necessarily backed by a thread. But a Task started with Task.Run is backed by a thread from the thread pool.